# How to count number of sentence using NLTK for a single string

Tags: python, nlp, nltk

I found code that takes a file path and extension as an input to count the number of sentences using NLTK (below) but nothing regarding how to apply this a single string stored in a variable.
Can this be done?

```
import nltk
folder = nltk.data.find(dirpath)
corpusReader = nltk.corpus.PlaintextCorpusReader(folder, '.*\.txt')

print "The number of sentences =", len(corpusReader.sents())
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the `sent_tokenize` function

```
from nltk.tokenize import sent_tokenize, word_tokenize

data = "All work and no play makes jack dull boy. All work and no play makes jack a dull boy."
print(sent_tokenize(data))
```

Output

```
['All work and no play makes jack dull boy.', 'All work and no play makes jack a dull boy.']
```